# How to remove some items from a big array

Tags: ruby

I want to check the files that don't exist, so I write a code as follows:

```
MAX_ID = 43148178
def extract_ids
  done = Dir['res/*.html'].map {|name| name[/\d+/].to_i}
  all = (1..MAX_ID).to_a
  all.delete_if { |i| done.include?(i) }
  all.shuffle
end
```

`ls res | wc -l` returns `35854`.

I find that this is slow. How do I do this effectively?

Comment: Creating an array with 43 million elements just to remove 35k rows sounds strange. What do you want to accomplish - a list of all the 43 million files that you're missing? And why do you need the shuffle() call?

Comment: Your code is effective, it's just not very efficient ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If 'done' is an array of items you wish to remove from the 'all' array, you can simply do this:

```
all = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
done = [1,3,5]
all - done
# => [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Or, as you want to change the all array

```
all -= done
```

Comment: `all -= done` will be much faster than `all.delete_if { |i| done.include?(i) }`